# Module not found: can't resolve @emotion/react/

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules, mern, emotion

I'm learning MERN stack project where I've proxy the frontend to backend on localhost. Everything works fine until I stop the react application to install some modules and then, on hitting the `npm start` command, I receive following errors:
[image]
*The list goes on*

Previous time when this happened, I received similar errors (like: **can't resolve 'fs'**, **'onAfterSetupMiddleware' is deprecated**, etc). I created a new folder named "frontend2" and used `create-react-app` command, installed all the dependencies again, and replicated the source files from original "frontend" folder. This worked till I again terminated the react app, after which I'm receiving new errors. I don't want this to keep happening and hence searching for a permanent solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Deleting your node modules and Package Lock json and install all the dependencies through `npm install`

Comment: Whenever I try deleting the node_modules folder, I always receive some kind of error and hence, unable to delete all files in node_modules. So, I'm creating another folder for frontend again and installing all dependencies. One thing I like to mention, every time I try to install any module, i receive some error by npm which forces to me install the module following with the ```--legacy-peer-deps``` command